# Structural Stability on Compact $2$-Manifolds with Boundary

Tags: real-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, smooth-manifolds

I'm studying the structural stability of vector fields and I'm interested in learning about this phenomenon on compact $2$-manifolds with boundary.

Let $M^2$ be a compact connected 2-manifold and $\mathfrak{B}$ the space of vector fields with the [$\mathcal{C}^1$ topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_topologies). The paper ["M. M. Peixoto - Structural stability on two-dimensional manifolds"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938365900182) defines structural stability as

[image: ![enter image description here]

Using this definition Peixoto was able to demonstrate the following theorem:

[image]

> **My Question:** I would like to know if someone knows a result, like the above, about
>   Structural Stability in a compact $2$-manifold with boundary (the case when $M^2 \subset \mathbb{T}^2$  is enough for my purposes).

---

### Just a few comments about my search for the result

Searching online I found the paper [Clark Robison - Structural stability on manifolds with boundary](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039680900832), however, the author defines a strange topology using the flows of the vector field, and I don't know if it is the same topology as in definition 1 or if it implies the result that I want. Moreover, the demonstration is a bit confusing and I think that important points are missing, *e.g.* the demonstration of Theorem C (in my humble opinion). Besides I don't even know if this would imply that the set of Vector Fields that are structurally stable would be at least dense in the set $\mathfrak{B}.$

His approach is using the $\mathcal{C}^1$-topology in the flow space, and not the $\mathcal{C}^1$-topology of the vector fields[image: ![Blockquote]
using this topology he proves the following theorem:[image]
the hypothesis of Theorem $A$ are:
[image]

where

[image]

---

It is also worth to mention that on the paper "M.C. Peixoto and M.M. Peixoto - Structural Stability in the Plane with Enlarged Boundary Condition", the following result was proved. Let $G\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a compact region, such that the boundary $L$ of $G$ is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ simple curve, then $X$ (a vector field in $G$) is structurally stable $\Leftrightarrow$ $X$ satisfies conditions $A$ and $B$, it has also been proven that the vector fields that this property possesses are open and dense $\mathfrak{B}$
[image]
[image]

---

Can anyone help me?